# Word for someone who abstains from eating mammal-derived foods (meat and milk)

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms, food

Is there a single word that refers to someone who doesn't eat food derived from mammals? This person would eat fish and other seafood, poultry, eggs, but would not eat the meat of mammals, nor anything made from the milk of mammals.

Comment: There's a list of terms [here](https://www.thespruceeats.com/types-of-vegetarians-3378611), none of which quite match but you could combine prefixes and suffixes and get something. (Made up words are frowned upon in ELU answers.) But if you want to explain your exact dietary requirements, you are better to explicitly say "I eat X Y Z, I do not eat A B C" rather than use an obscure term that people won't understand.

Comment: Yeah...I gottaa agre with @StuartF for the most part.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345315/is-there-a-word-in-between-vegetarian-and-non-vegetarian/345320#345320

Comment: Not quite - abstainer from red meat and milk products.

Comment: Then you'll have to add something like: Bill is a pollo-pescatarian who doesn't/can't/will not consume dairy products.

Comment: _Mafist_ is the closest term but your question is a bit more specific which includes not eating products made from the milk of animals also.  [Single word for someone who does not eat mammal's meat](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536069/single-word-for-someone-who-does-not-eat-mammals-meat/536071#536071)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the one linked. That asks for abstainers of red meat. Pork and rabbit are not considered red meat.

Comment: @Mitch The older question explains [**that they don't eat meat—but do eat fish and poultry**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195671/word-for-an-abstainer-from-red-meat), nothing about eating other types of white meat. The answers on the older question were objectively more nuanced also.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I missed the link to [singe word for someone who does not eat mammals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536069/single-word-for-someone-who-does-not-eat-mammals-meat/536071#536071). Which is definitely a duplicate and well answered. The red meat answer is what I consider not to be a duplicate. I think maybe the milk part is a distractor for this question?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, there is not an established English term to describe this. However,  I think I found a neologism...

[***Pollotarian***](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/pollotarian)

> A pollotarian is someone who eats poultry but not red meat or pork products.

-HealthLine.com

> People choose this dietary pattern for various reasons.
> For some, becoming pollotarian is a step towards becoming vegetarian, while others are more concerned about the health and environmental effects of eating red meat.

It is not an exact match, but your criteria are extremely specific, and may not have a a useful term...

Comment: Could be *saurophage*, too.

Comment: ...like lizard eating?

Comment: Yep, as desert dessert.

Comment: Holy Guacamoles, that sounds so yech...although I have dined on alligator tail in Fort Lauderdale...with a mustard sauce quite tasty...as they always say...tastes like chicken with a fishy accent, but really chewy. txs for the memories...